# How can I serve and get access to images in public folder as json?

Tags: node.js

I am told to simulate a node server that serves users profile info like name, profile image etc as json data. I only have some example images. They want me to use fetch to get the data as json. How will I be able to do that? Should I keep my images in public folder?

I'm not sure if putting the images in public and getting the path to it and sending json of that would work.

Comment: You can send the image url in the json or if you want you can serialize the image as base64 and send it in the json as string. I prefer to send the url.

Comment: Image url as in the url of the image folder in public folder?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Samra You still serve the public folder. In the json send the image url that you serve. Ex: `{ image: '/image/path/in/public/folder' }`.